# How to use a playwright instance in a heroku python application?

Tags: python, heroku, playwright

Currently I am trying to host and schedule a python script via Heroku. The script should use the playwright browser.

The problem is that, even with using the [heroku playwright buildpackage](https://github.com/mxschmitt/heroku-playwright-buildpack), it is not working. The deployment runs fine and in the deployment logs the installation of the buildpackage is highlighted.

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpacks:
       1. https://github.com/mxschmitt/heroku-playwright-buildpack
       2. heroku/python
-----> Playwright app detected
-----> Installing System Dependencies
Cloning into '.'...
Installing Playwright dependencies (env: PLAYWRIGHT_BUILDPACK_BROWSERS) for chromium,firefox,webkit.
-----> Detected Aptfile or Stack changes, flushing cache
-----> Updating apt caches
```

When I execute the script the following occurs:

```
Application Logs
2021-11-21T17:01:08.657708+00:00 app[advanced-scheduler.5395]: ╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
2021-11-21T17:01:08.657708+00:00 app[advanced-scheduler.5395]: ║ Looks like Playwright Test or Playwright was just installed or updated. ║
2021-11-21T17:01:08.657708+00:00 app[advanced-scheduler.5395]: ║ Please run the following command to download new browsers:              ║
2021-11-21T17:01:08.657708+00:00 app[advanced-scheduler.5395]: ║                                                                         ║
2021-11-21T17:01:08.657708+00:00 app[advanced-scheduler.5395]: ║     playwright install                                                  ║
2021-11-21T17:01:08.657708+00:00 app[advanced-scheduler.5395]: ║                                                                         ║
2021-11-21T17:01:08.657709+00:00 app[advanced-scheduler.5395]: ║ <3 Playwright Team                                                      ║
2021-11-21T17:01:08.657710+00:00 app[advanced-scheduler.5395]: ╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Locally everything works fine.

Code goes like this: (shortened for simplicity)

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://example.com")
    browser.close()
```

Python version to run is 3.9.9

Comment: Did you try to use docker to deploy your python script? I have the same problems as you.
I get a solution to use docker to deploy. But I didn't try that because I use the free account (500MB) and I need 2GB when I deploy docker so I can't confirm this is working but I think you should try.
This is a link: https://github.com/davidteather/TikTok-Api/issues/756